# SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input. at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, api, nodemon

**I'm a new developer learning how to work with API's and I've run into this error a few times now that keeps crashing Node:**

SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
at JSON.parse ()
at IncomingMessage. (/Users/dharmendrasingh/Desktop/WeatherProject/app.js:13:28)

I'm not really sure how to resolve it or what the problem is exactly... my JS code looks like this:

```
const express = require("express");
const https = require("https");

const app = express();

app.get("/", function(req, res){
  const url = "https://postman-echo.com/get?q=London&appid=639179c2c6d4f4db9c4657a69ac05438&units=matric";

  https.get(url, function(response){
    console.log(response.statusCode);

    response.on("data", function(data){
      const weather = JSON.parse(data);
      console.log(weather);

    });

  })
  res.send("Server is up and running");
})


app.listen(3000, function(req, res){
  console.log("Server is running at port: 3000.");
});
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Try printing out (somewhere) what the value of ```data``` is and check if it is indeed a valid JSON structure.

Comment: You're using the `https` callbacks incorrectly. You're meant to use the `data` event to build up the entire payload. Honestly, I'd avoid clunky utilities like `https` and use something more friendly like [got](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got), [node-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch) or Axios